# Is it a good idea to strip spaces from email addresses?

Tags: regex, forms, user-interface, authentication

I sometimes have messages from users saying that they can't log in. Most often I have found it's because they inadvertently added a space either before or after their email.

Is it a good idea to automatically strip spaces from emails on log in or on any form entry?

```
$email =~ s/\s//g; #strip all spaces out
```

Comment: space is not a valid character in email so yes you can strip out the space but in general you should only strip right most or left most spaces.

Comment: Strip leading spaces. Strip trailing spaces. Leave any other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [topic](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/110758/is-there-a-valid-reason-to-allow-leading-or-trailing-spaces-in-user-input) will answer most of your questions. I'm putting bellow a brief summary:

- **Emails/Usernames**: I agree with Rajwanshi, as spaces are not a valid character in emails, there is no harm in removing them. In the company I'm working for, we had the same problem that you are describing and removing all spaces turned out to be a good solution.
- **Passwords**: As they say [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/110758/is-there-a-valid-reason-to-allow-leading-or-trailing-spaces-in-user-input), you shouldn't trim or modify them in any way. Just hash them as is.
- **Other text inputs**: I would say to act depending on the context. But if you decide to trim, I would advise to do it on submit as it would not bring a good user experience to use online validation and bother users with an ending space.

Hope it will help you

Comment: I think it would be best to do it with Javascript on submit and not serverside, so on a successful log in, their browser will remember their actual email and not the one with the added space. Agree?

Comment: Trimming server side or client side will very likely be the same. Since you'll always trim email addresses server side, it doesn't matter if the browser remember an email with added space.

Comment: Your assertion that spaces are not a valid character in emails is technically not true. See https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5321#section-4.1.2, in particular the "Local-part" rule. If the local part is a quoted string, then spaces are valid and cannot be removed without changing the value of the email address. I would recommend using a library to parse and normalise email addresses, rather than trying to do anything yourself.